# How can I get selected image from gallery to my ImageView via registerForActivityResult() method with (Intent.ACTION_PICK)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Note: startActivityForResult() is deprecated. So I'm using this registerForActivityResult() method.

I'm using this code for this. But I can't get selected image from gallery to my ImageView.

My intent is running and I can select a image from gallery but I can't get image to ImageView.

How can I get selected image from gallery to my ImageView via registerForActivityResult() method?

Also I'm wanting to use (Intent.ACTION_PICK) and ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult().

Not mGetContent.launch("image/*") and ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() method option.

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.gallery)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent imgintent = new Intent();
                imgintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                imgintent.setType("image/*");
                imgactivity.launch(imgintent);

            }
        });
```

And

```
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> picactivity = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            pickimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pickimage);
// maybe useable for uri    pickimage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data.toUri(0)));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I read this documentation. mGetContent.launch("image/*") method is running fine for me. But this method isn't showing thumbnails for images on my tablet device. So I must use (Intent.ACTION_PICK) but I didn't do this. Because  (Intent.ACTION.PICK) is opening my gallery with thumbnails for images.

Comment: You should never be using `ACTION_PICK` for getting images. Use `GetContent`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, Why not?

Comment: "Because (Intent.ACTION.PICK) is opening my gallery with thumbnails for images" -- your tablet is one device. There are billions of devices. There is no requirement for any particular `Intent` action -- such as `ACTION_PICK` -- to offer thumbnails.

Comment: Ok. I will use GetContent. But also, Can I open direct with default Gallery apps for to get selected image? Because mGetContent.launch("image/*") is opening firstly (file.extension) view interface for images in device storage.